# Limit the memory and cpu available for a user in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, cpu-usage, pam

I am a little concerned with the amount of resources that I can use in a shared machine. Is there any way to test if the administrator has a limit in the amount of resources that I can use? And if does, to make a more complete question, how can I set up such limit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For process related limits, you can have a look in `/etc/security/limits.conf` (read the comments in the file, use google or use `man limits.conf` for more information). And as jpalecek points out, you may use `ulimit -a` to see (and possibly modify) all such limits currently in effect.

You can use the command `quota` to see if a disk quota is in effect.

Comment: All the inputs are commented,does that mean that there is no limit?.

Comment: Most probably, at least regarding CPU and memory usage. For disk usage I think you will need to check with the quota command

Answer (score 11):

You can try running

```
ulimit -a
```

to see what resource limits are in effect. Also, if you are allowed to change such limits, you can change them by the `ulimit` command, eg.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

lifts any limit for a size of a core file a process can make.

Comment: I realize this question is 3 years old, but the man page lists this program as being obsolete (says use `getrlimit` instead)

Comment: The ulimit() C library function is (see [ulimit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html)), the shell builtin is not (see [bash(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtin-Commands)).

Answer (score 1):

At the C level, the relevant functions (actually [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) could be [setrlimit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) and [setpriority(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpriority.2.html) and [sched_setattr(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setattr.2.html). You probably would want them to be called from your shell.

See also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) -and try `cat /proc/self/limits` and [sched(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html).

You may want to use the [renice(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html) command.

If you run a long-lasting program (for several hours) not requiring user interaction, you could consider using some [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing). Some Linux systems have a [`batch` or `at` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)#batch).